# Read bits from file and store it into char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, bit

I have a big text file that consists of 7000 entries of 512-bits each line and i would like to read each line and store it into a char array so that i can do bit operations.

Is there any recommended and efficient method?

Comment: 7000 lines x 64-bytes < 500,000 bytes, or not even 1/2 megabyte.  That is generally not considered "big".

Answer (score 1):

I would load the whole file, then have pointers to each 512bit blocks to the file in memory.

However you would need to provide some more information if you want a better answer.

---

```
char **load_file(const char *filename) {
   size_t i, j, file_size;
   char *file_ptr;
   char **entries;
   FILE *fd;

   fd = fopen(filename, "r");

   fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
   file_size = ftell(fd);
   rewind(fd);

   file_ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * file_size);
   fread(file_ptr, file_size, 1, fd);

   fclose(fd);

   /* 64 + 1 because newline is a character */
   entries = malloc(sizeof(char *) * file_size/(64 + 1));
   for (i = j = 0; j < file_size; i++, j += 64 + 1) {
      entries[i] = &file_ptr[j];
   }

   return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provided your own assumptions or code then I could better direct my answer, however here is a generic answer to your question...

---

You can use `fgets` (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)) to read the bytes on each lean and use bitwise operations to access each individual bit. Note you can have `fgets` read from `stdin` so you can pipe the file to your program (or use the file reading libraries to process it).

For the character array I would suggest using a dynamic array, not a finite array. If you are set on having a finite array then store it on the memory pool (not the stack) as the stack is susceptible to being overrun with large files (the size of your call stack depends on the architecture you are using).